# How to prevent UI freeze when binding an empty textbox using ValidatesOnDataErrors in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

**Answered in the comments** by @Bijington see Update 2

I am having a bit of trouble with the UI freezing on me when I beginn to hover over an empty Textbox bound to a property of an object.
I can no longer interact with my app and the CPU usage goes up from about 5% to over 50%. This only happens when I set ValidatesOnDataErrors to true and the textbox starts out marked as invalid (which is intentional).

Here is some possibly relevant shortend code:

Object that provides the Data

```
public class Product : Item
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return row.Field<string>("name");
        }
        set
        {
            row.SetField<string>("name", value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public override SelectTables Table
    {
        get
        {
            return classToSelectTables<Product>();
        }
    }

    public override object[] ItemFields
    {
        get
        {
            return row.ItemArray;
        }
        set
        {
            row.ItemArray = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemFields");
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public override string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Der Name muss zwischen " + MinLenght + " und " + MaxLenght + " Zeichen lang sein.";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Errorcheck " + errorMessage);
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }

    public Product() : base() { }

    public Product(ref DataRow row) : base(ref row) { }
}
```

The class doing the binding

```
class ItemBinding<T> where T : Item
{
    private ItemViewModel<T> viewModel;
    public ItemViewModel<T> ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return viewModel;
        }
    }

    private string CurrencyFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return "C";
        }
    }

    public ItemBinding()
    {
        viewModel = (ItemViewModel<T>)getViewModel(Item.classToSelectTables<T>());
    }

    private Binding getBinding(PropertyPath path, string format = null)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = path;
        binding.Source = viewModel.Temporary;
        binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        if (format != null)
        {
            binding.ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            binding.StringFormat = format;
        }
        return binding;
    }

    public void doDefaultBinding(TextBox text, PropertyPath path)
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(text, TextBox.TextProperty, getBinding(path));
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the base class Item

```
    public abstract class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    protected DataRow row;

    public abstract object[] ItemFields { get; set; }


    public long? Id
    {
        get
        {
            return row.Field<long?>("id");
        }
    }

    public abstract SelectTables Table { get; }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public abstract string this[string columnName]
    {
        get;
    }

    public Item()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("new " + typeof(Item).ToString());
        if (row != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        row = Tables[(int)Table].NewRow();
    }

    public Item(ref DataRow row) : this()
    {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public DataRow getCopyOfRow()
    {
        DataRow row = Tables[(int)Table].NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = (object[])this.row.ItemArray.Clone();
        return row;
    }

    public static SelectTables classToSelectTables<T>()
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        return DatabaseManager.getTable(t.Name);
    }

    public void add()
    {
        Tables[(int)Table].Rows.Add(row);
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        if (row == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        row.Delete();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("PropertyChanged");
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
Turns out I am a moron. I forgot to not set a path for the tooltip in the textbox style. Now it works:

```
            <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Where is your `IDataErrorInfo` or `INotifyDataErrorInfo` info implementation?

Comment: @  Bijington In the base class 'Item'.

Comment: sorry I thought I scrolled through that full section. Are you seeing any binding errors in the Output window?

Comment: @Bijington No there are no binding errors. I can even successfully add and edit products using this binding as long as I don't hover over the textbox when it is empty.

Comment: Are you using a custom style for the TextBox? It sounds like it is the process of trying to populate the ToolTip that is causing the problem which in the base style I believe should just be your error message.

Comment: @Bijington That did the trick. I totally missed not setting the damn path to the tooltip. Thanks.